# SPA .htaccess breaks JS files after top level

Tags: .htaccess

I'm making a single page application that must be able to accept deep links, but having trouble with the .htaccess setup. Here's my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

http://example.com/1 works fine, loading index.html and all linked JS files without issue.

http://example.com/1/2 breaks however, loading index.html correctly but all the JS links break because they're reinterpreted like this "1/build/js/myjsfile.js"

Here's what my js link tags look like:

```
<script src="/build/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

I could use an absolute url for the JS src, but want to avoid that if possible because the project is shared between multiple project members working on machines with different IP addresses.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Double-check you are indeed using "root-relative" src links, as they should work as well as absolute URLs. I.e., the condition you are describing shouldn't happen when using root-relative URLs.

Comment: `the project is shared between multiple project members working on machines with different IP addresses.` Not sure why that matters actually. But you can put this `<base href="http://www.example.com/" />` in the head section of your html page which should also work.

Comment: Thank you, @PanamaJack, I actually tried that earlier but a server cache tricked me into thinking that it had no effect. <base href> and a cache refresh solved my problem.